# Mod rewrite removes parameters from URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm losing URL parameters when I do mod_rewrite, and I don't understand why...

I've had to add a country code to the URL, for localisation. So my old URL:

The original URL:

```
www.domain.com/mail_confirmation.php?id=222
```

now looks like

```
www.domain.com/us/mail_confirmation.php?id=222
```

Mod rewrite should call:

```
www.domain.com/mail_confirmation.php?id=222?country=us
```

And this is the rule I need help with. It doesn't do what I expect it to, and loses the parameters along the way:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.+)\?(.+) $2?$3&country=$1
```

Another rule that might be affecting is this one, at the very beginning of the file:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/?$  index.php?pais=$1
```

Do you see any mistakes here? I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` needs to be

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.+)$ $2?country=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Please, note that URL parameters are **not** available for matching within the `RewriteRule`. If you simply need to append an extra URL parameter you can do so along with the `[QSA]` flag which would take care of appending the original URL parameters for you.